# Ubuntu MongoDB server not responding?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, database, mongodb, ubuntu-18.04

I have `amazon` `aws` `ubuntu 18.04` server 8GB RAM and 50GB Storage. I have installed `MongoDB 4.2` and `Node JS 12 LTS`.

In current server has 30 GB `MongoDB` storage. I have 4 micro service on same server. I have installed `pm2` to start all 4 services.

Don't know why my all services responds delay.

For example:

I have checked `pm2 start 0` it takes 4-5 mins to show logs.

I have already remove db caching and flush `pm2` logs. But still `mongodb` service takes 50% CPU usage.

I have checked all code and found there is no 3rd party APIs call and optimize all queries and adding indexing on server. But still server taking too much times.

Most of time I got server timeout error. Please assist me. How to make my `server` fast.

Comment: what's the output of `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6`? If is `0`, then you should add some directives in your `sysctl.conf` and reload kernel parameters.

Comment: @Marcel yes it is `0`. What should I add in `sysctl.conf` file?

Answer (score -1):

TL;DR: I recently troubleshoot a node server that was trying to resolve names on IPv6 before falling back to IPv4, and this was the solution to my problem (YMMV):

Try the following:

- Open Terminal
- Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and open the configuration file and add the following lines at the end

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

- Type command `sudo sysctl -p` you will see this in terminal.

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

- After that run `$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6` - If it reports `1` means you have disabled IPV6.

Restart your node server.

HTH

Comment: Hope it works for me.

Comment: Warning: This disables IPv6 but does nothing to resolve whatever the underlying problem is.

Comment: It doesn't help me.

Comment: how many CPU cores you have in that VM? 8GB ram seems like a notebook. Put more $$ into that.